# R Shiny: works locally but failed on server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

My shiny dashboard works successfully on R-studio.  Recently, I moved it to the AWS EC2 Ubuntu server.  I deployed a test app and it works fine.  However, the main shiny app doesn't work at all. It says **"The application failed to start. The application exited during initialization."**

I checked the log and it seems the app cannot recognize any variable from Global Environment which fails the app.  Since my data is over 8 GB, the Shiny app would not work if I put "readRDS" inside the app.R file. When I built this app under R-studio, I always load all the files and variables to the global environment before I start my shiny app. It seems this method is not working under the Shiny server.

Is there any other method that I can let my shiny app recognize all the variables that I preloaded to the Global Environment under the shiny-server?

If no, is there any alternative way that I can make my shiny app work and avoid loading 8GB files every time I start it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the max size of input dataset as shown below.  It needs to be defined just above the server call.

```
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=10*1000*1024^2)   ###  maximum input dataset size is set to 10GB

# Define server logic here  ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {…}
```